# How to add Julia Kernel to JupyterLab Desktop App and adding Julia Environment in Anaconda?

Tags: python, julia, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have added Julia kernel to my JupyterLab. But I can't see it JupyterLab Desktop App. What should I do? I have added R and Python kernel using Anaconda, but I can't add Julia :(

Comment: What have you tried? Have you installed Julia from [conda-forge](https://github.com/conda-forge/julia-feedstock) already? If yes, have you tried installing [IJulia](https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl)?

Comment: If any of the steps failed were there any errors?

Comment: @krassowski Hi. I didn't use conda forge, I just used IJulia and its notebook function. When I want to install Julia by using conda, It gives error :(

Comment: @krassowski Gives an error like this : The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - julia

Comment: @ÖmerÜnaldı try adding conda-forge to channels list `conda config --append channels conda-forge`. Then do a search `conda search julia`.

Comment: (base) C:\Users\Ömer Ünaldı>conda search julia
Loading channels: done
No match found for: julia. Search: *julia*
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel
r-julia                          1.1   r36h6115d3f_0  pkgs/r
r-juliacall                   0.16.6   r36h796a38f_0  pkgs/r
sos-julia                     0.18.2            py_0  conda-forge
sos-julia                     0.18.5    pyhd8ed1ab_1  conda-forge

Comment: @emrahgunduz it says like that

Comment: @ÖmerÜnaldı looks like there are no windows versions for julia under anaconda and conda-forge channels. have you tried downloading/installing from julia's web site?

Comment: @emrahgunduz I have installed Julia from its website. I have used original Julia while adding it to Jupyter but, I have installed JupyterLab desktop a couple hours ago and I selected my Anaconda Python environment, it loaded python and r , but there is no julia. Bu if I want to use Julia from JupyterLab's browser , it works well. I have used Pkg.add("IJulia") from Julia command-line.

Comment: @emrahgunduz I think I just need to installing a Julia env in Anaconda Navigator, then it will work.

Comment: If you install it from Anaconda Navigator it may end up in a different environment than intended. Have you followed https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-desktop/blob/master/user-guide.md ?

Comment: Another option is to use [`nb_conda_kernels`](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda_kernels) to make specs visible across environments.

Comment: @krassowski I have tried this https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-desktop/blob/master/user-guide.md. In the browser version, I can see Julia and R. But In the JupyterLabDesktop, I couldnt see Julia. My R version is 3.6.3 in JupyterLab Desktop but in Browser, my R is 4.1.1. I don't know why... :(

Comment: I would recommend: removing Julia installed from Julia website, configuring your conda to use conda-forge channel, installing Julia into a chosen conda environment https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/julia, changing the environment in JupyterLab Desktop using the environment selector on statusbar.